# identify if httpServeltRequest came from a mobile or web

Tags: servlets, mobile

I want to identify if a http request came from a mobile app.

My apporach was to check the referer, since mobile app usually don't send the referer in the request.
But there are some smartphone's os which send permanent values in the referer, so I can I recognize that?

I attach a link about windows 7 and windows 8 phone, they send referer.
http://atomaras.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/wp7-app-on-wp8-breaking-changes-part-1-webrequests-referer-changes/

Answer (score 0):

You should rely on the [`User-Agent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#Format) HTTP request header instead that contains the browser information. This link [here](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html) seems to have a list of User-Agent headers that can come from different mobile browsers.

Comment: thats the right answer, although, remember that this field can be set programmatically

Comment: Right, I think OP's intent is to identify but not verify if the client is really a mobile browser, so if some program is trying to behave as a Mobile browser, it's fine for OP to treat such requests accordingly.